# Webcam simulator / virtual camera in c# -DirectShow

Tags: c#, winforms, webcam, directshow, simulator

I have to create a virtual cam in c# asp.net  which should be accessible in skype and adobe live flash encoder. In c#, I have found only this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437617/DirectShow-Virtual-Video-Capture-Source-Filter-in)  describes how can achieve this. But when trying with the source code they provide, I'm getting two errors ,

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   An error occurred while writing the registration information to the registry. You must have administrative credentials to perform this task. Contact your system administrator for assistance   VirtualCam C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\VirtualCamSrc\Sources\VirtualCam\RegAsm
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   The command ""C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\VirtualCamSrc\Sources\VirtualCam\bin\x86\Debug\install.bat" VirtualCam" exited with code 100. VirtualCam   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 4935

I have given full control permission for HKEY-CLASSES-ROOT.

And when I'm trying with thier binary code, command prompt says

> RegAsm : error RA0000 : Unable to locate input assembly 'VirtualCam.dll' or one of its dependencies.

Can you help me to solve this issue? My system is 64 bit operating system.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with asp.net? Safe your self some time and buy one of the existing virtual webcams.

Comment: I've used Streamcoders to do this in the past (I am not affiliated, just a customer).
https://streamcoders.com

It's not cheap, but they have a virtual camera that can accept images from .net (C# sample included)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. Right click on Visual Studio shorcurt or executable, Run as Administrator and you'll be ready :-)